# Quick start in Spring and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

I have good knowledge of C++ and Core Java but now I am assigned in a project which requires Hibernate and Spring. Please provide me some links so that I can work on that project!

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: I really like answers here but I did not know abt acceptance ...now I'll do Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring: See the introduction material listed at the top of the [documentation page](http://www.springsource.org/documentation) and the [reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

Hibernate: [Getting Started guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/) and the [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/). Also the [annotation reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/) if you plan to go that route (recommended).

Comment: As a beginner, which should I start with ?